# Fatal error encountered during MySQL command execution in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013

Good day,

I have developed an app which manages sport timing. I am reasonably experienced in Visual Studio 2013 and MySQL 5.6, the language and DB I use. I have extensively tried to solve my problem by reading up on similar errors encountered.

I have a table in the MySQL DB that I want to export to a .csv file, but when I programmatically execute the statement I receive a "Fatal error encountered during command execution" error message.

I printed the SQL command to a MsgBox, copied and pasted the command in MySQL Workbench and the command executes fine and creates the .csv file.  Any help to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub FullSetToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FullSetToolStripMenuItem.Click
  Dim ExportQuery, SqlQuery As String
  Dim Comm As New MySqlCommand

  With sfdExportResults
   .InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\"
   .Title = "Export CSV Files"
   .CheckPathExists = True
   .DefaultExt = "csv"
   .Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*"
   .FilterIndex = 1
   .FileName = Me.EventCode
   .ShowDialog()
  End With

  FullSetPath = Replace(FullSetPath, "\", "/")
  ExportQuery = "select 'racetime." & Me.EventCode & "' into @tableName; " _
                & "select """ & FullSetPath & """ into @outputFile; " _
                & "select group_concat(concat(""'"",column_name, ""'"")) " _
                & "into @columnNames from information_schema.columns where table_name=@tableName;" _
                & "SET @query = CONCAT(""select * from ((SELECT "",@columnNames,"") UNION (SELECT * FROM '"",@tableName,""')) " _
                & "as a INTO OUTFILE '"", @outputFile, ""' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'""); " _
                & "PREPARE stmt FROM @query; " _
                & "EXECUTE stmt;"

    MsgBox(ExportQuery)
    MsgBox(FullSetPath)
    Try
        Comm.Connection = Conn
        Comm.CommandText = ExportQuery
        Comm.ExecuteScalar()
        MsgBox("CSV successfully exported to: " & FullSetPath)
    Catch MySqlCmdExeError As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error exporting CSV file: " & MySqlCmdExeError.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The command text generated by the software which successfully executes in MySQL Workbench:

SELECT 'racetime.DD0010' INTO @tableName;
SELECT "C:/Users/Peter/Desktop/DD0010.csv" INTO @outputFile;
SELECT group_concat(concat("'",column_name, "'")) INTO @columnNames FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name=@tableName;
SET @query = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ((SELECT ",@columnNames,") UNION (SELECT * FROM '",@tableName,"')) AS a INTO OUTFILE '", @outputFile, "' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;

I successfully used another command previously which created the .csv file, but without column headers, therefore the new command I constructed above which is giving the error. The previous working command:

```
ExportQuery= "SELECT * FROM " & Me.EventCode & " INTO OUTFILE """ & FullSetPath & """ FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';"  'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Thanking you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: There is an InnerException? If yes what is its message?

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for taking time to look at my problem.  I've added some code to display the InnerException.  This is the message - Parameter '@tableName' must be defined.

Comment: This is very difficult for me to understand. That query cannot execute in Sql Workbech either. Not realy sure that is syntactically correct. However, in NET if you put a parameter placeholder (the `@tablename` and other `@xxxx` as well) then you need to supply the value for the placeholder adding a new MySqlParameter to the MySqlCommand.Parameters collection. Without an exact match you should see the mentioned error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Steve. I've executed the query line for line and printed all the MySQL variables and found the @query to have contained an error. The single inverted commas around `@tablename` was to blame, and after removal the query executed perfect in MySQL Workbench. Unfortunately it is still not working from my VS application. I have not used MySqlParameters in VS, but have relied purely on creating a query that I have witnessed executing in Workbench.

Comment: The error is still: Parameter `@tableName` must be defined. So from that I understand that `@tabelname` does not receive a value in VS.  Am I correct in saying that?